# barplot design issues

Tags: r

I am doing a barplot of 14 columns to represent some data, I set the names.arg option to show as vertical lables, unfortunately, this caused the new vertical lables to overlap with the "sub" and "xlab" options I have. How do I prevent this from happening?

Here's my command:

```
par(mar=c(6, 5, 4,7.5 ))
barplot(x, main=paste("title1 \n","subtitle"),
names.arg=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14),las=2, sub=("overlapping text1"),
xlab="overlapping text2", col = c("red2","darkorange3"))
```

Another question on my mind is, I am using a 2-line title in "main" as you can see from the command. Is it possible to make the second line font smaller, whilst keeping the first line in the same format?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution to change font size for one of titles, is to use two calls of functions `mtext()` in different lines with different `cex=` values and remove `main=` from `barplot()`. To overcome problem with overlapping text, `mtext()` also can be used instead of `xlab=` and `sub=`. You just have to find the right `line=` and increase space around plot with `par(mar=..)`.

```
x<-sample(letters[1:14],300,replace=TRUE)
par(mar=c(9,3,5,2))    
barplot(table(x),
        names.arg=paste0("very_long_",1:14),las=2, 
        col = c("red2","darkorange3"))
mtext(side=3,"Title1",line=2,cex=2)
mtext(side=3,"subtitle",line=1,cex=1.5)

mtext(side=1,"overlapping text1",line=6)
mtext(side=1,"overlapping text2",line=7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Didzis. The title is working fine now. I took the tick away because the overlapping text thing did not work for me. Note: before aplying the barplot function, i used par() to do the dimensions, is that why the mtext not working at the bottom? please see the edit up to see my par function. NOTE: I tried to et the mtext on the side 1 to line=20 and line = 30 and it is still overlapping.

Comment: You just have to increase numbers in par(mar=...) till whole texts fits in plot window, for example, par(mar=c(9, 5, 5,7.5 )).

Comment: God! I'm sorry dude! I was adjusting the second parameter instead of the first in the par() function lol. Many thanks :) all working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to look at is the `staxlab` function in the plotrix package.

Also look at the `mgp` argument to the `par` function for a way to set the default placement of the axis title.